# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.| A child container failed during start

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-orm

here trying to create a spring MvcOrm project, where with this file trying to add dependency jar to my project, but after including hibernate-core dependency jar file tomcat server failed to start and throwing a different-different error like

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:,
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:``

I've tried everything, Thanks in advance.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyMwZ.png)[list of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06wKq.png)[list of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYAFS.png)

pom.xml file

enter code here
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.raj.spring
    springormmvc
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    springormmvc Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <project>1.8</project>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: do you have any other service running at port 8080?

Comment: this is most surely related to a corrupted jar, try recompiling

Comment: port 8080 is free to use

Comment: and another answer for currupted jar is, even when i am using latest version of eclipse i.e. 2018-12 with latest version of jar file, i'm getting the same error.

Comment: any of your jars could be corrupted. take a look at that ugly LOC error. That's a corrupt jar

Comment: Try to delete your maven repository (`<users>/.m2` directory), then rebuild project

Comment: answer to currupted jar is, maven is using only those dependency jar's which is been suggested by eclipse ide only in dependency tab of pom.xml file.